# How to update the object in setState if the questionID same otherwise add to setState

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

There is a react questionnaire component which add selected answers to `this.state = { answer: []}` which works fine. At the same time when the user update answer it add as another object. Is there any option to update the object in `setState` when the **questionID** is the same ?

```js
onChange(event) {
  const field = event.target.name;
  let question = event.target.dataset.questionId;
  let result = event.target.value;
  let answer = {
    'questionID': question,
    'answerValues': result
  };

  this.setState({
    answer: [
      ...this.state.answer,
      answer,
    ]
  });

  console.log(this.state.answer);
}
```

Currently same question adding like this

```
[ 
  {
    "questionID": 1,
    "answerValues": 2
  },
  {
    "questionID": 2,
    "answerValues": 5
  }
  {
    "questionID": 1,
    "answerValues": 1
  }
]
```

any solution to update the object if already exist same `questionID` is `this.state.answer` ?

Comment: What have you tried? How does it fail? This question doesn't show any attempt at solving this on your own.

Comment: @ChrisG why should I post here if I knew the solution ?  I couldn't find solution  and looking forward good developers who is kind to share knowledge. others are here for giving down vote 

Comment: "What have you tried?" is not asking you to post the solution... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @ChrisG You can see in the question what tried so far and I don't know the solution that is why I am here 

Comment: Your question shows code that appends the new answer, it doesn't show code that tries to conditionally append it based on an existing ID. You have almost 12k rep, why do you argue with the basic rules of this website?

Comment: @ChrisG You are the person came to the question and arguing against the question. As you can see below the developers sharing ideas and giving answers which they thing the best, I also do the same (instead of criticising people who coming here to get solutions)  that is how got 11k rep so far

Comment: Looking at your previous two questions, one is a clear duplicate and the other is OT here and should go on codereview instead. You're stubborn though so who cares? I don't. Bye.

Comment: @ChrisG So I am happy with stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce like that :

```
this.setState({
  answer: this.state.answer.reduce((acc,ans)=>{
    return ans.questionID === answer.questionID
      ? [...acc,answer]
      : [...acc,ans]
  },[])
})
```

Comment: with this solution state seems to be empty. Initially the `this.state = { answer: []}` is empty does it make any issue

Comment: Erf... I just forget to return inside the reduce... should be ok right now

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like with array [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
this.setState({
    answer: this.state.answer.map(
     (existingAnswer) => (existingAnswer.questionID === answer.questionID 
        ? answer : existingAnswer)),
  });
```

Comment: with this solution state seems to be empty. Initially the `this.state = { answer: []}` is empty does it make any issue ?

Comment: Having initial state empty is fine since `map` iterates over array items. Problem would be only if `this.state.answer` would not be an array

Comment: oh really, based on the question it is pushing like this `[ 
  {
    "questionID": 1,
    "answerValues": 2
  },
  {
    "questionID": 2,
    "answerValues": 5
  }
  {
    "questionID": 1,
    "answerValues": 1
  }
]`

Comment: If the array is empty, your answer will never insert any new answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use object assign, in this code, you will be able to update the question if it already exists by ID else it will be adding a new question

```
  const field = event.target.name;
  let question = event.target.dataset.questionId;
  let result = event.target.value;
  let newAnswer = {
    'questionID': question,
    'answerValues': result
  };
   this.setState(prevState => {
            const user = prevState.answer.find(d => d.questionID === newAnswer.questionID);
            if (!!user) {
                Object.assign(user, newAnswer);
                const data = prevState.answer.map(d => d.questionID === user.questionID ? user : d);
                return { answer: data }
            } else {
                return { answer: prevState.answer.concat(newAnswer)};
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

like Martin said use

```
let questionExistsInState = (this.state.answer.some((ans) => (ans.questionId === answer.questionId)));
let newState = []
if(questionExistsInState) {
  newState = this.state.answer.map((ans) => (ans.questionId === answer.questionId ? answer : ans))
} else {
  newState = [answer, ...this.state.answer]
}
this.setState({
    answer: newState ,
  });
```

Also I see that you are using setState in an onChange event. Please note that setState is not a synchronous operation, it is not guarenteed that you will see the new state if you are console logging immediately after setState() call. You can console log in the callback(second argument) of setState function.

Comment: `let questionExistsInState = this.state.answer.some(ans => ans.questionId === answer.questionId);` Also, it seems that this code once again replaces the previous question with the same ID, instead of appending the answer value.

Comment: updating to some. Regarding second part, that what is asked to do right. If question id already exists replace it with new answer, else append the new data

Answer (score 1):

I suggest storing answers as an object where the key is the question id and the value is the answer. In your constructor:

```
this.state = { answer: {}}
```

Then in `onChange()`:

```
this.setState({
    answer: Object.assign({}, this.state.answer, {
        [question]: result,
    });
});
```